# Generic type for argument that is also a return value

Tags: java, generics

I have a non-generic code like this:

```
class List {
  List intersect(List out, List other) {
    if (out == null) out = new List();
    // insert elements common to $this and $other into $out
    return out;
  }
}
```

That method is safely used with mixed types of contained objects:

1. `other` can contain objects of more specific type (subclass)
2. `out` can contain objects of less specific type (superclass)

E.g. (not from real code)

```
List<Number> my;
List<Integer> other;
List<Object> result = new();

result = my.intersect(result, other);
```

What I need is therefore:

```
class List<T> {
  <R super T> List<R> intersect(List<R> out, List<? extends T> other);
}
```

However this does not compile. Generics FAQ states that lower bound for type parameter does not make sense but I can't see it given above example.

The closest I get is:

```
List<? super T> intersect(List<? super T> out, List<? extends T> other);
```

But this requires explicit casting of return value at the call site.

Is it possible to generify this method in a way that would be type safe for all existing usages ?

**UPDATE:**
In case it is not obvious: this is not a java.util.List (which is an interface btw.) but a custom class. Irrelevant parts were omitted, but method signature is exactly as shown (except for access level).

**UPDATE2:**
By type-safe I mean restricted as much as possible. Ideally all parameters shall observe both rules laid down above.

Comment: Is `intersect` a static method? If not, I'm a bit confused why there's the list instance itself and 2 list arguments?

Comment: Just a side note: are you aware of the method List.retainAll: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29
?

Comment: It's not static and it's not a java.util.List

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to break the rules of covariance and contravariance. Let's say you expect a `List<Object>` as your `out` parameter and T is some class A, and there is some other class B that extends A. The implementor of your `intersect` method creates a `List<A>` for `out`, which seems fine because A extends B. But the caller gets a list he assumes to be a `List<Object>`. Now the caller tries to insert a bunch of C's (unrelated to A and B except that all three derive from Object at some point) and the whole thing explodes.

In other words, this isn't possible.

Comment: While I get a feeling that it is indeed not possible to restrict types as much as I want, I don't quite follow your example.


It is perfectly fine to pass any list for `out` where `out.T` is less specific than `T` and then insert anything conforming to (subclass of) `out.T` into resulting list.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Since I completely misunderstood the question, here a new try for an answer.

I first wanted to answer

```
class List<T> {
      /**
       * Creates the intersection of this list with a second list,
       * adding the resulting elements to another list.
       * @param out the List to which the output should be added.
       *     If null, a new List will be created.
       * @param second the second list to intersect with this list.
       * @return out, with the intersection of left an right added
       */
   <R super T, S extends R>
      List<R> intersect(List<R> out, List<S> second);
}
```

but as you found out, it does not compile. **Yes, I think this would be a valid use of the `super` keyword.**
It looks like there is no way to make something like this compile.

(I know that you said that S should be a subtype of T, not only of S, but I still don't see this as necessary. In fact, S could possible be anything, but leaving it a subtype of R allows more freedom for implementations. It does not really matter here.)

Interestingly, it is possible to formulate it as a static method:

```
class List<T> {
      /**
       * Creates the intersection of two Lists,
       * adding the resulting elements to another list.
       * @param out the List to which the output should be added.
       *     If null, a new List will be created.
       * @param left the first list to intersect.
       * @param right the second list to intersect
       * @return out, with the intersection of left an right added
       */
    static <R, T extends R, S extends R>
        List<R> intersect(List<R> out, List<T> left, List<S> right) {
        // TODO
        return out;
    }
}
```

Or, if you don't need T and S inside the method:

```
class List<T> {
      /**
       * Creates the intersection of two Lists,
       * adding the resulting elements to another list.
       * @param out the List to which the output should be added.
       *     If null, a new List will be created.
       * @param left the first list to intersect.
       * @param right the second list to intersect
       * @return out, with the intersection of left an right added
       */
    static <R>
        List<R> intersect(List<R> out, List<? extends R> left, List<? extends R> right) {
        // TODO
        return out;
    }
}
```

Of course, this static way to say this does not work when you want to override this method in subclasses.

Comment: In your examples R is not limited in any way by `List.T`.  
In other words it fails condition 2:  
 `out` can contain objects of less specific type (superclass)

Comment: OK, looks like I misunderstood your question ... I'll adapt my answer later.

Comment: So, new answer. By the way, if your code samples had a javadoc comment, I would have understood it right away :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<R> List<R> intersect(List<R> out, List<? extends R> other)
{
    for(R x : other)
        if(this.contains(x))
            out.add(x);
    return out;
}

boolean contains(Object x){ ... }
```

notice that `contains()` takes `Object`, instead of `T`

Comment: As mentioned in another answer, your example allows unconstrained return type, which is more permissive than my condition 2 (T extends out.T).